# Import GIT Repository files into TFS without any GIT baggage

Tags: git, tfs

I have inherited a GIT repository from which I would like to extract the files only and no GIT related aspects or files. I want to do this because I want to put the entire folder tree into TFS without using GIT at all. I understand that by doing this I will lose any historical information relating to changes made previously in files.

I googled this and was unable to find what I was looking for.

Code: N/A

Want windows file folder tree without any GIT information within

Comment: What did you google? Sounds like you want to "checkout" and then copy/paste?

Comment: Yes, I guess functionally I want to do a "checkout" but how would I do that? Is "checkout" a GIT command that can be run against a repository such that the result would be a tree containing only the files not related to any aspect of GIT?

Comment: So...did it work?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the files only, and you don't want any history at all, then all you need to do is (from a Windows command prompt):

1. Clone the Git repository:

`git clone path/or/url/to/repository`

2. Get the files from whichever branch you want to use:

`git checkout master` or some other branch

3. Delete the Git directory:

`rd .git /s /q`

Now you have a set of files you can add to TFS.

(Now this does *exactly* what you want, but there are also tools such as [git-tf](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=gittf) and [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) that may be able to preserve the history for you.  Unfortunately, it appears that they're both end-of-life, but that doesn't necessarily mean they don't work anymore.  Unless you're certain you don't want the history, you might consider trying these out.)

Comment: I cloned the repository to a file named VerEngine3_0.

Comment: Then at the command line I entered as you suggested and got the error below

Comment: Directory of C:\WORK\VerEngine3_0

05/23/2019  09:23 AM    <DIR>          .
05/23/2019  09:23 AM    <DIR>          ..
05/23/2019  09:23 AM             3,164 .gitignore
05/23/2019  09:23 AM    <DIR>          .idea
05/23/2019  09:23 AM    <DIR>          .vs
05/23/2019  09:23 AM    <DIR>          DllCommunicator
05/23/2019  09:23 AM    <DIR>          Surface
05/23/2019  09:23 AM    <DIR>          VerificationEngine
05/23/2019  09:23 AM             4,168 VerificationEngine.sln
     
             

C:\WORK\VerEngine3_0>git checkout master
Already on 'master'

C:\WORK\VerEngine3_0>

Comment: At the command line I entered git checkout master as you suggested and got

Comment: That's fine.  It's not an error.  Keep moving forward.